# Environment variable in Node.js (VS Code) is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, express, environment-variables

I am trying to set a environment variable in Windows 10 command line with this command:

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

When I use `echo %NODE_ENV%`, it is working just fine.

But when I use `process.env.NODE_ENV` inside VS Code, it is still undefined.
I tried to set this variable inside VS Code command line, but doesn´t work either. This doesn´t work with any environment variable (PORT, etc.)

I also tried to use `app.get("env")` which is set to development by default. When I set `NODE_ENV` to something else, it doesn´t work as well.

Do you have any idea, where is the problem? Do I have to configure something somewhere? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Did you restart VS Code from the shell in which you set the variable? (If you set an environment variable at the command line, it will only be seen by processes started by that command line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `require('dotenv').config()` in your application

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#usage

Comment: I work, thanks! But, I suppose that this file should be in .gitignore, right? Because, when I want to store there a password, it would be visible, right?

Comment: The password that you want to hide could stay in a file called `.env` and in the `.gitignore` you can add the env file. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#faq

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that pops to my mind is to restart the server. I've forgot about it numerous of times.